# Attaching variables and random numbers to results from a wikipedia search bar

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Link to full project:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kg9e7e2ce5j6bjd/WorkingProject.zip?dl=0

Screenshot of what it looks like right now:

[image]

In the screenshot there is only one item displayed but if you scroll down, the price is the same for each one and I would like to change the code so that it's a different random number (I'm using math.random()) for each item in the list.

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to get:

1. Price as a random number for each item
2. Avilability as a random number for each item
3. Quantity as a random number for each item
4. Image as a google search attached to the userinput (whatever they typed into the search bar)
5. Link to bidding page to keep the variables consistent

Full html code (wiki.component.ts):

```
import { Component }        from 'angular2/core';
import { JSONP_PROVIDERS }  from 'angular2/http';
import { Observable }       from 'rxjs';
import { WikipediaService } from './wikipedia.service';
import {Router, RouteParams, RouterLink, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'Wikithing',
  template: `
    <h1>Search and Display Page</h1>
    <p><i>Fetches after each keystroke</i></p>
    <input #term (keyup)="search(term.value)"/>
    <ul>
     <li *ngFor="#item of items | async">{{item}} <br> <p> 

      </p> Price (in USD): $ {{Prices}}
       <br> <p> 

      </p> Availability: 24 hours <br> <p> 

      </p> Quantity currently in stock: {{quantity}}

       <br> <p> 

      </p> Image of item: <img src="http://weknowyourdreamz.com/images/apple/apple-05.jpg" alt="Apple" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
       <br> <p> 
       </p>
               <p>

            </p>
             <a [routerLink]="['BiddingPage']">Click here to bid on this item.</a>
            <p>

                </p>
        <br> <p> 
       </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  providers:[JSONP_PROVIDERS, WikipediaService],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterLink],

})
export class WikiComponent {
  constructor (private wikipediaService: WikipediaService) {}
  items: Observable<string[]>;
  quantity = Math.random() * 100;
  Prices = Math.random() * 1000;
  image = 0;
  search (term: string) {
    this.items = this.wikipediaService.search(term);
    var Prices = Math.random() + Math.random();
    var quantity = Math.random();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using Observables here I would try to solve this in a reactive way. This means that you could transform your response, which is coming from your `WikipediaService`, to what you want. At the moment your `items` is of type `Observable<string[]>`, but what you actually want is an array ob objects because you want to add properties such as `quantity` or `prices`. So you could do the following to transform your response:

```
this.items
  .map((items) => items.map(() => ({
      name: item,
      price: Math.random(),
      quantity: Math.random()
      availability: Math.random()
      link: ...,
      image: ....
    })));
```

Then you get an array of objects so you have to change your view accordingly. For example

```
</p> Price (in USD): $ {{item.price}} <br> <p>
```

Also make sure to fill out `link` and `image` as to what you want. So if you want the link to be what the user input you have to create a form control and get the input in your component. Another way is to use `[(ngModel)]` on your input to save the value in a variable in your component.

For more information about forms check out those links:

1. http://learnangular2.com/forms/
2. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot.